# Select rows from pandas dataframe with dates

Tags: python, pandas

Given a simple data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
```

I can select the records with the labels 1 and 3 using

```
df.loc[[1,3]]
```

But, if I change alter the index so it uses dates...

```
df.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=5)
```

this no longer works:

```
df.loc[['2010-01-02', '2010-01-04']]
```

> KeyError: "None of [['2010-01-02', '2010-01-04']] are in the [index]"

How can `.loc` be used with dates in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is convert dates to [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) or [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then it works nice:

```
print (df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-02', '2010-01-04'])])

                   0         1         2
2010-01-02  0.827821  0.285281  0.781960
2010-01-04  0.872664  0.895636  0.368673
```

---

```
print (df.loc[pd.to_datetime(['2010-01-02', '2010-01-04'])])

                   0         1         2
2010-01-02  0.218419  0.806795  0.454356
2010-01-04  0.038826  0.741220  0.732816
```

Comment: Doh! I was trying to look up by a string rather than a date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the boolean mask from [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html#pandas.Index.isin):

```
In [151]:
df[df.index.isin(['2010-01-02', '2010-01-04'])]

Out[151]:
                   0         1         2
2010-01-02  0.939004  0.236200  0.495362
2010-01-04  0.254485  0.345047  0.273453
```

Unfortunately partial datetime string matching with a list won't work currently so either this or actual datetime values need to be passed